# Scroll to Bootstrap Panel body on click of related link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long list of panels that are tiresome to scroll though. I'm trying to put a shortcut of links at the top of the page.

Shortcut code:

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" >
    <img src="obama.jpg"  class="img-responsive" />
 </a>
```

Going to:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"  id="obama">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        // rest of panel1's code
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            // panel body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work in some regard. When I click on the shortcut it opens the panel. Now I just need to scroll to it.

I've tried:

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   var id = $(e.target).prev().find("[id]")[0].id;
   navigateToElement(id);
})

function navigateToElement(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

But to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what actually this `$(e.target).prev().find("[id]")[0].id`  suppose to give from your given `HTML` ?

Comment: Here's where it's from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633087/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-3-collapsed-accordion-panels-load-at-top-of-their-conte

I'm new to javascript so I'm not quite sure :(

Comment: can you tell me what id you need actually that you are passing in `navigateToElement(id)` function ?

Comment: I suppose it would be `#collapse1`. Perhaps `#obama` would work somehow. The thing it that it would be different every time since I have a whole page of panels with unique ids.

Comment: collapse1 or collapse because collapse1 is not the id ?

Comment: My bad, I changed the code to make sense. Sorry

Comment: can you please edit your code if any changes . Because it's getting really tough what you want and what you code .

Comment: And FYI accordion is not the id .Give me the correct HTML and I will try to help you then .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" >
    <img src="obama.jpg"  class="img-responsive" />
</a>
<div class="panel panel-default"  id="obama">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        // rest of panel1's code
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body" id="panel-body1">
            // panel body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   var id = $(e.target).prop('id');
   // To scroll to panel-body (untested)
   // var id = $(e.target).children('.panel-body').prop('id');
   navigateToElement(id);
});

function navigateToElement(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdlubrano/zm2qnjnf/ (shrink your screen to see if the page scrolls properly).

Comment: Awesome! It seems to work. One question, how could get it to scroll to the top of the panel title instead of the panel-collapse? Is there a way to have the offset be the height of the panel-title? `var id = $(e.target).sibling('.panel-heading').prop('id');` doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `var id = $(e.target).parent('.panel-default').prop('id');` works. Thanks!